# streams in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Can anyone help me better understand how to write a stream?

I understand that a stream is an infinite sequence of values and the way I have learned programming them is a representing them as a thunk that when called produces a pair of (1) the first element in the sequence and (2) a thunk that represents the stream for the second-through-infinity elements

For example:

```
(define powers-of-two
    (letrec ([f (lambda (x) (cons x (lambda () (f (* x 2)))))])
        (lambda () (f 2))))
```

I understand here that it is just producing a powers of two and to access these for example calling `(car (powers-of-two))` would result in `2` and calling `(car ((cdr (powers-of-two))))` would result in 4

Now I am trying to write a stream called `red-blue` that alternates between strings `red` and `blue` but I am a little confused about how to construct it

Comment: so you've done it, congrats! Check out the Scheme section in http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SieveOfEratosthenesInManyProgrammingLanguages for a working example of SICP-styled streams. There is only one macro rule there, you can apply it manually throughout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a general understanding of streams in Scheme, I'd recommend section [§3.5 Streams](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_sec_3.5) in the SICP book. It'll teach you the basic concepts to solve stream-related problems such as the one in the question.

Regarding the problem in the question, here's the general idea to solve it:

- Build two infinite streams, one producing only the string `"red"` and the other `"blue"`
- Combine both streams taking one element from one and then one element from the other (alternating), this procedure is called `interleave` in SICP

Answer (score 14):

It looks like you were asking how to build your own custom streams with thunks, which others have already answered. Just in case, it's worth noting that Racket has a stream library built-in and most Racketeers would use that for streams.

Here's an example:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/stream)
(define reds (stream-cons "red" reds))
(define red-blues (stream-add-between reds "blue"))

;; show ten of them
(for ([i 10] [e (in-stream red-blues)])
  (displayln e))
```

Answer (score 7):

I wrote [SRFI-41](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41) which describes streams, provides an implementation, and gives many examples. The streams there differ from those in SICP, and are "better" in a way explained in the SRFI.

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie at this but the following solutions seems to work as well:

```
 (define red-then-blue
   (letrec ([f (lambda (x) (cons x(lambda ()(f(cond [(string=? x "red") "blue"]
                                              ["red"])))))])
   (lambda () (f "red"))))
```