# Andrew's Curves: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I was trying to make Andrew's curves work with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import andrews_curves

def andrews_curves(df, class_column, normalize = False):
    plt.style.use("ggplot")  
    plt.figure()
    andrews_curves(df, class_column)
    plt.draw()

andrews_curves(players, "RANK")

plt.show()
```

Where `players` is my dataframe. And it gave up with a warning:

```
More than 20 figures have been opened
```

And then:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

This only happens with Andrew's Curves, since Parallel Coordinates works fine with almost the same code:

```
def parallel_coords(df, class_column):
    plt.style.use("ggplot")
    plt.figure()
    parallel_coordinates(df, class_column = class_column, cols = list(df), alpha = 0.4)
    plt.draw()

parallel_coords(players, "RANK")
plt.show()
```

I've tried to use `clear('all')`, `clf()`, and `cla()` methods, but they all have zero effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename the function `andrews_curves` in your code.

It seems that what you *want* to do, is call `pandas.plotting.andrews_curves`, within your own `andrews_curves` function.

Trouble is, as soon as you define andrews_curves, this replaces the other object of the same name, so the effect of calling your function is that it calls itself recursively, until it hits pythons recursion limit:

[Why does Python have a maximum recursion depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873627/why-does-python-have-a-maximum-recursion-depth)

This doesn't effect `parallel_coords`, because the function you're calling within there has a different name.

In short, rename your andrews_curves function something else:

```
def plot_andrews_curves(df, class_column, normalize = False):
    plt.style.use("ggplot")  
    plt.figure()
    andrews_curves(df, class_column)
    plt.draw()
```

and you won't have this issue.